# calling stored procedure in Entity framework database first - Column generation issue in result class

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6, ado.net

My stored procedure is returning result from 2 select statements based on the condition(like below),
when i generate edmx file input and result class for this stored procedure, Tn the result class I'm only getting ID,name and DateIn.
DateOut column is missing from the result class.
Please help me to get this column in edmx using entity framework database first approach.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetStocks]  
(  
@id INTEGER
)  
AS    
BEGIN  
if @id=2
select ID,name,DateIn from dbo.StcokIn
else 
select ID,name,DateOut from dbo.StockOut;
END
```

I generated edmx file but i didn't get  DateOut column in result class.

```
namespace ConsoleApp6
{
    using System;

   public partial class GetStcoks_Result
   {
       public int ID { get; set; }
       public string name { get; set; }
       public string DateIn { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I want to get missing DateOut column in GetStcoks_Result class.

Comment: You got first name not last name : select ID,FirstName  Should be select ID, LastName, FirstName

Comment: Without modifying SP Do we have any option to retrieve FIRSTNAME column using entity framework?

Comment: No.  The SP either returns ID and LastName; or ID and FirstName.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify you're SP like below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetPersons]  
(  
@id INTEGER
)  
AS    
BEGIN  
if @id=2
select ID,FirstName='', LastName from dbo.Person
else 
select ID,FirstName, LastName='' from dbo.Person;
END
```

Now again update you're EDMX and you will get that column.

Comment: Hi harsha,Is there a option to get this column(FirstName) through entity framework without modifying stored procedure?

Comment: No @user1928165, Entity framework will take the columns which we are mentioning in SP. So, we need to specify those columns also while we are using any conditionslike above. Otherwise, Instead of this SP, you can write LINQ query in your code to get this same result and write a view model class for returning result.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you selecting a single property  based on the input parameter and still want to model your object with both properties? why not make a standard procedure that will return both properties and then use the desired property if not both in your application?

```
  CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetPersons]  
 (  
   @id INTEGER
   )  
   AS    
   BEGIN  

   select ID,FirstName, LastName from dbo.Person where id = @id

    END
```